# Installed fprint, can't login anymore

Tags: 12.04, command-line

Tried **Fprint**, was stupid enough not to backup the `common-auth` file before changing it.
Somehow I'm locked out of the system, trying to **fingerscan** doesn't do any difference. Even when I've done it 5 times and it asks for password, when it asks for password and I write it in and it says that it's the wrong password. I use the same password for root as for my user.

Tried to go into `Recovery Mode` -> `root` -> `sudo nano /etc/pam.d/common-auth` and remove the rows saying that you need the fingerprint to login, but when I try to overwrite, it says the file is read only, even when I try to open it with root.

I have a lot of schoolwork files and programs on the system, so I can't afford losing them.
Help?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't have any idea about your fprint problem but you must mount the file system as rw on recovery mode to make some changes. After opening the system via recovery mode run this command first:

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

Answer (score -1):

Use an usb ubuntu live and edit the **/etc/pam.d/common-auth** and remove this row **auth sufficient pam_fprintd.so**

Edit the file on the hard disk where you installed linux, not the live usb.

Comment: What help to edit common-auth on the live boot media ?

Comment: Improved the explanation, though it was obvious that it should change the file on the hard disk and not the live usb!